# Django filtering with query with many objects

Tags: python, django, django-models

sorry, I can't imagine better title for my question

I have two filters

```
themes = Theme.objects.filter(grade = st.grade) # returns many objects
tests = Test.objects.filter(theme=themes)
```

I want to return all objects, that equal to any object from themes, but it returns only objects then equal to first object from themes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If theme in `Test` is `ForeignKey` to `Theme`, you can do it in one query:

```
tests = Test.objects.filter(theme__grade=st.grade)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `in`:

```
tests = Test.objects.filter(theme__in=themes)
```